# Best Practices for Removing Unused Code

Tags: c#

I'd like to know what people's best practices are for removing unused code. Personally I'm a fan of deleting (not just commenting) anything that's not currently being used. But I'm unsure of how far to go.

Take this as an example (although I'm interested in general discussion). In my project I have a dozen or so UserControls. For a feature that later got canned, I implemented a couple of methods and properties on one of the UserControls. The additional code is not specific to the feature, but needed to support it. It may potentially be useful later on.

- Should I remove the code because we're not using it at the moment, and the less code there is the easier it is to read? The problem with this is, how do future developers know that this work has already been done?
- Or should I keep it there, so another developer can find it easily if they need to use it later (they're not going to think to go through source control to see if anyone had done this and deleted it)?
- Or is there another option?

The same applies to UserControls not currently being used. Should I remove them or keep them?

**Edit:** It goes without saying (or I thought it would) that we're using source control.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The first thing to remember is **all your code should be in source control**.

With that in mind, of course you want to delete obsolete code rather than just comment it out. Commented code blocks of any length are *dangerous*, for at least two reasons:

1. There's a tendency to assume that the comments were maintained with the rest of the code. This isn't true and can lead to problems like bug regressions.
2. It's easy to miss an uncommented closing curly brace (for example) in the middle of a long block.

The deleted code is still available if you really need it, but it's no longer cluttering up your working copies. If you're *really* concerned about discoverability for the old code you can leave a comment indicating code was removed and the revision number you need to find it. At one line, that's a lot better than what the actual code block was using. It's also much clearer this code has been allowed to lapse, and for exactly how long.

Comment: Suggest adding a #3: Unused code is not likely to be tested well and could theoretically introduce bugs and/or security holes.

Comment: That fall under 'maintenance', so it's pretty much the same as reason #1.

Comment: +1. I also find that commented out blocks of code seem to draw your attention whilst scanning through - you don't want to be distracted by  dead code.

Comment: I have to admit, this is a really good answer, and it is probably better than anything I would have though, in my case, I guess, I would have simply left it there, uncommented.

Comment: I think the bit that really sealed it for me that I hadn't considered properly before, is that the code wouldn't have been tested and future users may not be aware of that

Comment: Love the idea of removing them and leaving and comment referring to the revision number. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a source control system, deleting the code is my preferred option.

It won't get in your way when working with the current code, and you'll always have the code in the repository if you ever need it again.

Comment: "[Since you're] using a source control system, deleting the code is my preferred option."  -- there, fixed that for you.

Answer (score 5):

A piece of code can have two states.
Either it is active, functioning and tested, in which case it should be in the source control
Or it is obsolete in a way that you can't imagine anyone ever wanting to use it anymore, simply because it is obsolete. In this case it should be deleted.

Not erasing code so that "another developer can find it easily" is a perfectly good reason to keep the code active and compiling. Don't worry about the size of your libraries, the linker removes anything that isn't used.

If you're erasing code and want to warn others of the code that was there and for the reason it was deleted so they won't do the same mistake again, a good comment can be put in place.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that even if you comment that it's in the repository, it'll be re-written instead of someone going back and grabbing it.

Not that I've worked in many places with this "no code left behind" policy (just one), but I've NEVER seen someone go back into the repository and get some old code.

However, except for small blocks, I've never seen anyone uncomment someone else's code either!

If you wanted to save it, I'd leave it fully implemented and tested (check in the tests!) but under a condition that will change if the new code is ever needed.

I've had un-needed code just "Turn on" when it was needed, that's a really nice feeling (not that it can always be done).

If you can't be bothered to make it fully functional and tested, then snip it and let the next guy re-write it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also a fan of deleting unused code.

If I know that the code can be helpful later, I created a branch before deleting the code from the trunk (we're using subversion - so creating branches is very cheap and easy). This allows me to easily get that code back once/if it is needed.

For example, if you have a new feature, which won't be completed for a release, this procedure allows to remove the partial feature from trunk, but you will be able to add it back once you're gonna finish it.

Answer (score 2):

I usually let dead code idle for a while until its use has stabilized & I won't be using that functionality anymore. At that point, I remove it.

Answer (score 1):

We have an "Obsolete" area in our source tree where we move stuff that is no longer used. It is away from the trunk in an area that isn't normally checked out, so nobody has to look at it.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by an "Obsolete" area?

Comment: @alvaronortes a folder called "Obsolete" where old code is still visible but removed from the main build.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest replacing the deleted code with a comment specifying the Work Item against which the code was deleted. My rationale is this provides a "hook" onto which any code review comments can be attached. We're using TFS change sets to do code reviews VS Professional. If the code is 100% deleted there is no hook.

Answer (score 0):

My preferences as an OCD person:

- Code should be in source control, which by using PR, the code is always available as well as using the git history even if we deleted the branch
- follow the no code left behind's policy and seems so rarely somebody retrieve the old code or even uses it without testing and rewriting it
- Just think of all the next poor developers that inherited the code to maintain and develop who will be puzzled all about which part is in use or is not in use and had to go over all commented code as well, besides their daily tasks.
- We can use the correct attribute for in-use code but for unused code, we should delete it and not comment it out, but after a short period of time.